# Amount of random tests generated by QuickChick in Coq

Tags: libraries, coq

Whenever I use QuickChick in Coq, it has a default of 10000 tests. Is there a way to change this default value to generate a different amount of tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out a way:

```
Extract Constant Test.defNumTests => "42".

QuickChick test_predicate.
```

Will test `test_predicate` up to 42 times:

```
+++ Passed 42 tests (0 discards)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also try using `QuickChickWith`, `stdArgs` and `updMaxSuccess` as follows:

```
    QuickChickWith (updMaxSuccess stdArgs 42) test_predicate.
```

However, most of the time I use your extraction hack to avoid large natural numbers.